# How to decide the level of multiple level paging

Tags: osc

Given a computer system with a 64 bit virtual address and 8 byte per page entry, let the physical address be of 48 bits, and the system is "byte-addressable". Assume that every page is of 4KB. Then:
I known the maximum number of frames = 2^48/2^12 = 2^36.
But suppose that we have multi-level paging. How many levels do we have in multi-level paging?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information to decide that. You could theoretically have one single level table with 2^36 entries. You could also have a 36-level setup with each table only containing 2 entries. Current designs typically use between 2-4 levels...

Comment: Ya. That's what bothers me. I found this question from my OSC past final exam and it didn't have answer. So according to your answer, there is no clue in the question to decide how many levels...No matter what, I really appreciate your response.

Comment: If that's the extent of the information, yes, it's underspecified. However, it's entirely possible that they're looking for "propose a specific solution and prove that you are capable of thinking through the details and evaluating the tradeoffs" - a question that would have several "right" answers, as long as you prove you have mastery of the concepts involved....

Comment: Got it. For multi-level paging, I know that it is to reduce the page table size in memory. Think about it if there are 2^36 entries and one for 8 bytes, then we may need extremely large memory space. But it also has disadvantage that we need more than one time memory access which will reduce the performance of effective memory access time. Finally, thanks again for your information and help. ^^